# At what point does a human become self-aware?

Tags: consciousness, self, awareness

What are the conditions for being self-aware? If this answer can not be answered by naming specific traits, behavior unique to a self-aware being, complexity of development or other tangible concepts, is there at least a time frame after conception, when we suspect self-awareness arises?

EDIT: As pointed out in one of the comments, my question lacks more information on the research I have done prior to asking it. The background for my question, arises from a discussion of pre- and postnatal development of humans during a seminar held at [Department of Psychology at Charles University](https://kps.ff.cuni.cz/en/) of Prague. So far, I have come across a lot "we don't really know", "many signs ..of self-awareness", biased religious theories, or answers more specific, but philosophical. Accurate methods of testing, such as [MSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_test), do not provide a good general answer. So, to rephrase my question a little, is there some kind of general / 'official' concensus on the subject?

Comment: It would be a pretty long answer because there's no dominant theory what self-awareness means. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-awareness#Developmental_stages for image or https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3898688/  for body etc.

Comment: @Fizz I think you could make a fairly short answer out of that. List some possible 'checkpoints' and some estimated ages associated; I don't think it would have to be completely comprehensive or definitive to be a good answer and would show clearly that a consensus is not possible.

Comment: @BryanKrause - I second that - an answer doesn't have to be *the* answer.